# How Sniper Bot Watcher feature on poocoin.app works?

Tags: bots, blockchain, binance-smart-chain

I have recently discovered Sniper Bot Watcher feature on poocoin.app website(https://poocoin.app/sniper-watcher).
Any chance someone can give me an explanation on how it works?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i see on that list, the bot watcher looks at "0x3ae4222d06dacba3618526359a25bee8aecdbd92" this contract, and looks at incoming transactions in that contract and somehow finds all the info there not sure how though and clearly it dosnt list all the transactions there.
Not sure how those bots work but I'm guessing they snipe through that contract and it's a known bot contract so poopcoin watches it.

EDIT: The watched contract is actually bogged finance contract, and you have to hold atleast 750 bog to use it. The contract is just orders people can make. And bog finacnce runs the bot and buys the orders that are in the contract.